# Can not get Google Analytics custom vars to work

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to get the custom variable options to show in google Analytics.
Here is my java script I am using but it is not recording much - there is data - but nothing based on my pageview and user sessions.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

```js
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-127xxxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, 'Subscriber', 'no', 2);


</script>
```

ga('send', 'pageview');

pageTracker._setCustomVar(2, 'Subscriber', 'no', 2);

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use custom vars with Universal Analytics (which for all practical purposes means you cannot use custom vars anymore - this is a deprecated feature supported only by deprecated code). Use [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) instead.

To use a custom dimension you first have to configure it in the property settings. As you are using this to store a subscription status you probably want a user scope variable (hit level pertains to individual interactions, session level to visits - "subscriber" seems to be a property of a recurring user rather than a session level dimenson).

While you give a name to the custom dimension in the tracking code you address it via it's numeric index (first dimension created will have index "1" etc.).

There are two ways to set a custom dimension in the code - either via a set call or as a part of the pageview. A set call applies to all subquent interactions; if you have created the variable in the session scope you might as well use "set" (since it applies to all interactions of the user in any case). You need to "set" the dimension before the pageview call (or other interaction call), else it will not be sent.

So the complete code will look something like

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-127xxxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Subscriber');
ga('send', 'pageview');


</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Custom Vars are deprecated, and probably don't work with the new Universal Analytics code that you used.  You want [Custom Metrics and Dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).

Second, if you used the old code, you'd want that `pageTracker._setCustomVar` line to go before the `ga('send', 'pageview');` line.

The second thing also applies to the metrics/dimensions!

Good luck!

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en